# Which object initialization style is more appropriate in C#?

Tags: c#

Which object initialization style is more appropriate in C#?

- Declare private object and initialize it in the same line:

  ```
  private List<ReportRow> rows = new List<ReportRow>();
  ```
- Declare private object and initialize it in the constructor:

  ```
  private List<ReportRow> rows;
  ```

  In constructor

  ```
  rows = new List<ReportRow>();
  ```
- Declare private object and initialize it in the method where it is used:

  ```
  private List<ReportRow> rows;
  ```

  and in my Run() method

  ```
   rows = new List<ReportRow>();
  ```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of them are appropriate.  It really depends on the details of the code.  If you're simply initializing the field to an empty list my preference is to initialize it in-line with the declaration.  If you're putting values into a list dependent on constructor parameters then I go with initializing it in the constructor.  If the population is expensive and possible to skip then I'd go with initializing it the first time the consuming code is called.

Answer (score 1):

Your first two options are identical; you should use whichever one you find clearer.
You should also make the field `readonly`.

Your third option is different; the field will remain `null` until you call `Run()`.
That's probably not a good idea.

Comment: Identical is not accurate. The field initializers are called before the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The option

> declare private object and initialize it in the method where it is used.

is the best - if it is used in one function then there is no need to initialize it in the constructor or declare it at class level.

You should look to initialize objects in the constructor when you are assigning values that are passed in (injected) on the constructor. Declaring it in the constructor means it is localized to that scope, and initializing it in the constructor doesn't make much sense if it isn't used in the constructor and is only used in one method - it should be scoped to that method.

Comment: Also, if it is only used in one method and it is reinitialized each time the method runs, it should probably be local to that method, and not a class member variable.

Answer (score 0):

I would comment on slugster's answer and mention that even if an object is only used in one method, it could still be best to declare it at the class level if it is expensive to initialize it.  You can still initialize it in the method it is used, so that it is only done if necessary.  But, with a member variable, you can check to see if it is null before initializing it, so that it is only done once.

This question makes me miss the static local variables in C++, although even those wouldn't help if you need a different object for each instance of the class.